# Android: Delivering your own ads through webview

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to create my own sort of (mini) ad network to cross-promote our own apps. I do not want to use admob or any other SDK because I am under the impression that they do not work any more for under 3.0 Android SDKs, the app is must to run over Android 2.3

After explaining this, I wrote a html page and uploaded to our server (snippets are taken from web):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="banners.js">
<style>
html {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</script>
</head>
<body style='margin:0;padding:0;' onLoad = "javascript:rotateBanner();javascript:setInterval('rotateBanner()',20000);">
<a href= "http://www.bigfoot.com/~java4free" onMouseOver = "javascript:pause()" onMouseOut = "javascript:resume()">
<img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" src = "first1.jpg"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript for that will be:

```
<!-- //Hide from non-javascript browsers

//Author: Mark Ganson
//Date: 3/10/2000
//Site: http://www.bigfoot.com/~java4free

var nCurrentBanner = 0;
var bPause = false;

//replace these links with the appropriate href portion of your banner code
//example: <a href="java4free.html"><img src="java4freebanner.jpg></a>
//in the above example, "java4free.html" is the link string
//and "java4freebanner.jpg" is the image string

//href parts
strLinks = new Array (

"http://www.commission-junction.com/track/track.dll?AID=10347&PID=296657&URL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ecj%2Ecom%2FAffiliate%2Findex%2Easp",

"http://www.bigfoot.com/~java4free.html"

);

//img parts
strImages = new Array (

"http://myserver.co.uk/banners/first1.jpg",
"http://myserver.co.uk/banners/first2.png"

);

//status bar messages
//comment out this block if you don't want status bar messages
strMessages = new Array(

"Commission-Junction.  Get paid!",
"Java4Free!  Free webtools for webmasters!"

);

function rotateBanner(){

    if (bPause){
        return;
    }

    //following code assumes that the banner will be the first link/image
    //in your html page.  If this is not correct, you will need to modify
    //the value in between the [] accordingly.  For example, if you have
    //2 banners appearing before this banner in your html, you would replace
    //the [0] with [2] in the lines below.

    document.links[0].href = strLinks[nCurrentBanner];
    document.images[0].src = strImages[nCurrentBanner];

    //comment out the following line if you don't want status bar messages
    window.status = strMessages[nCurrentBanner];

    //now rotate for next iteration
    if (nCurrentBanner < strLinks.length-1){
        nCurrentBanner++;
    } else {
        nCurrentBanner = 0;
    }
}

function pause(){
    bPause=true;
}

function resume(){
    bPause=false;
}
```

Then I created a webview through XML

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and then I inserted this code into my onCreate method of my activity where I want to show the ads

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    wv.loadUrl("http://myserver.co.uk/banners/banner.html");
```

**Questions are:**

1. The above javaScript is safe enough for this kind of thing? I previously once used document.write method and the site got hacked after sometime, not sure about this time now.
2. This displays the ads fine but I guess because the image is in an enclosing html page, when I call

   wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

The viewport resizes it to very small and the 320x50 image do not remain the same.

Please help.

Comment: related to admob, it works for 2.2, you just have to compile under 3.2 or some version like that, but you can specify a lower min-sdk

Comment: Thanks, I tried adMob once more and it works, using the House Ads of adMob will be a good option rather than using inferior ad network of our own. Thanks again.